# Add Subview within a custom subclassed UICollectionViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

This might be a simple question but I can't get it work nor can I find an answer to the question.

I am trying to add a subview to a custom subclassed collectionviewcell when calling a method from the viewcontroller.

I have a `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` created in the viewcontroller. When I click one of the cells, I call the `addOverlay` method in the custom cell class to add a subview but this does not seem to show up. Any help would be useful. Thank you

Sample code:

`func addOverlayView() {
        let overlayView = UIView(frame:  CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        contentView.addSubview(overlayView)
}`

Comment: Did you call `reloadAtIndexPath` or `reloadData()` after adding your subView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get a proper cell reference like this at the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method?

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? YourCustomCollectionViewCell {
   cell.addOverlayView()
}
```

Comment: YES. I was dequeuing a new cell for some reason. Thank you